# JS: Filling 3 fields with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this function to fill a `textfield` with Javascript:

```
function addMsg(text,element_id) {

document.getElementById(element_id).value += text;

}
```

This is getting activated when people click this link:

```
<a onclick="addMsg('THIS IS THE TEXT ADDED','TEXTFIELDNAME'); return false;">CLICK HERE TO FILL THE FIELDS</a>
```

But now I want to fill 3 `textfields` with one click.
So if people click the link, 3 different values have to be added to 3 different textfields.

Is this possible? And how can i fix this?

Comment: So add more arguments to the function, and do the same thing. What's the problem?

Comment: Or simply call the function three times with different sets of arguments.

Comment: Or pass arrays. There are so many easy ways to do this, take your pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the same thing that already you have used in your code.  Fill the values by getting their IDS.

```
function fillThreeTxtBoxes(text1, text2, text3) {
 document.getElementById('textfieldID1').value = text1;
 document.getElementById('textfieldID2').value = text2;
 document.getElementById('textfieldID3').value = text3;
}
```

In jQuery,

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
 $('#textfieldID1').val(value1);
 $('#textfieldID2').val(value2);
 $('#textfieldID3').val(value3);
})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer.
But i'm not that familiar with jQuery and javascript.

I understand the function, but don't know how i apply it to my link.

Cause' this is the link now? 

    $('a').on('click', function() {
    $('#textfieldID1').val(text1);
    $('#textfieldID1').val(text2);
    $('#textfieldID1').val(text3);
    })

?

Comment: @PatrickAkkers Ok, can you let me know what are the 3 values to be filled?

Comment: Well, i send ID, NAME and EXTENSION to the textfields.

Comment: @PatrickAkkers Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Cnrn7/.  I have made a very simple for your understanding using elementIDs

Comment: Wow, thank you, that's really obvious to understand this way.
I'm going to work with it! thank you verry much.

Answer (score 0):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ItoQEXI/2/edit)

Let's say you have:

```
<a onclick="addMsg(['Test 1','Msg 2','333'], 'field'); return false;">CLICK</a>

<input class="field" type="text">
<input class="field" type="text">
<input class="field" type="text">
```

your function:

```
function addMsg(arr, cls){

  $('.'+ cls).each(function(i){
    this.value = arr[i];
  });

}
```

Comment: Thank you,

This seems logic, but i don't understand exactly, because all the fields need to be named "field".
After submitting the form i can't save it to the database this way, because $_POST['field'] will have one value?

Comment: @PatrickAkkers oh, sure, sorry, Changed to use `class` insted of `name`